# PHP gd2 and pdo_mysql errors

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I have a PC running PHP7.2 and a laptop running PHP7.4 and on both I installed the `php7.x-mysql` and `php7.x-gd` but I am getting these errors. It worked before, but after upgrading my laptop to 7.2 and it didn't work, I tried the same for my desktop and now I have these errors. Does anyone have a solution?

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: /usr/lib/
php/20170718/gd2 (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), 
/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file 
or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib
/php/20170718/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718
/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on 
line 0
```

```
/usr/lib/php/20170718$ ls
calendar.so  fileinfo.so  json.so       pdo_pgsql.so  readline.so   sysvsem.so    xml.so
ctype.so     ftp.so       mysqli.so     pdo.so        shmop.so      sysvshm.so    xmlwriter.so
curl.so      gd.so        mysqlnd.so    pgsql.so      simplexml.so  tokenizer.so  xsl.so
dom.so       gettext.so   opcache.so    phar.so       sockets.so    wddx.so
exif.so      iconv.so     pdo_mysql.so  posix.so      sysvmsg.so    xmlreader.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir,
First find out which version of PHP your Apache2 is picking up for your running website. You can check it via

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then to run multiple PHP version I'll suggest having a look how to install multiple version and to configure them via FPM. Just a caution, FPM works great on local but not for servers. So, install multiple version from either of the links.
[First Link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-different-php-versions-in-ubuntu/)
[Second Link](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/)

For FPM installation see this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my apache is picking up 7.4 on my laptop (which it should) and 7.2 on my pc (which it should).

I don't really want to run multiple versions, I just want 7.4 to work on my laptop

Comment: Now, you've to ask yourself a couple of questions and act accordingly. Which version of PHP you're using, the FPM version or NON-FPM. In FPM version you tell apache via configuration in the host.conf file. But, the simplest answer would be to install the GDP version for 7.4 and 7.2 and all other things you need. After the installtion restart apache. Thanks!